# Word for what a "handyman" does?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage, etymology

For the past several weeks, I've been trying to figure out the word for what a “[handyman](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/handyman)” does. Last night I heard someone on the TV downstairs say “this is my *[handiwork](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/handiwork)*,” and the connection suddenly seemed so obvious.

Earlier today I did some research—looking through the dictionary definitions of both words and using [Google Advanced Search](https://www.google.com/advanced_search) to try to find cases in which the two words were used together—in hopes of confirming my theory. However, I was unable to find any reference to the words ever being used together.

So my question is twofold:

- Are *handyman* and *handiwork* at all related?
- If not, is there a word to describe the work that a handyman does?

Comment: Did you check the OED? There's actually an interesting tale here. See *“enta **geweorc”*** at *Beowulf* line 2717,  “the work of ents” (where *ents* is the old word for giants), or *“eald enta geworc”* from the Old English poem, “The Wanderer” (*eald* was how they spelled *old* back then). We might call that *old entiwork* today by analogy with *handiwork*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The word ***handiwork*** first appeared in Old English, where it was written as two words, *hand ᵹeweorc* meaning “hand work”. The OED provides this citation:

> ***c.* 1000** Ælfric *Deut.* **iv.** 28. And ᵹe þeowiaþ fremdum Godum, manna **hand ᵹeweorc**.

That smattering of Old English might in Early Modern English run more along the lines of *“And ye shall worship foreign gods, the work(s) of men’s hands.”*

About the word’s history, the OED also writes:

> OE. had also *handweorc* **ʜᴀɴᴅᴡᴏʀᴋ** containing the simple *weorc*, work.  As *ᵹeweorc, iwork* did not survive in ME., *handiwerc* was naturally analysed as a compound of the simple *werc*, with *handi*, often written separately, and treated as an adj.: see **ʜᴀɴᴅʏ**.

Morphologically, that *ᵹeweorc* there was a past participle form; think modern *wrought*. In this particular instance *ᵹeweorc* was functioning as a collective, so more in the sense of *works* than just plain *work*. Its curious *ᵹe-/ge-/ye-/y-/i-* prefix you might recognize from German past participles; it’s the same as we see in the archaic word *yclept*. Middle English saw OE *handgeweorc* worn down to things like *hondiwerc* and *handiwork*.

Because Modern English past participles did not survive with their Germanic prefix intact, in Late Middle English *handiwork = hand + iwork* was reanalysed as *handiwork = handi + work* instead, creating a novel adjective *handy* and applying it to the noun *work*.

So our word *handy* came from people thinking that the *y-* from the obsolete *ywork* got moved over to the noun *hand* in *handiwork* to make an adjective: *handy work*. *Handy* therefore originally meant *manual* in that it was *hand* + *y*, but it has come to mean more than that by extension. *handy* is more apt to mean “useful” than manual when used standalone.

So yes, ***handyman*** is indeed related to ***handiwork***, but not at all in the way one might imagine. The adjective *handy* came from *handiwork* through reanalysis, and then later got applied to the various manual labors of a handyman.

The word ***handicrafts*** also comes from that reanalysis to create a compound word for  craftwork done by hand. ***Handicap*** is less clear, however.

Comment: "King Ælfred the Great"? Here in Wessex, we know that Alfred was an Englishman, and are deeply suspicious of suggestions that he might be Saxon (isn't that some sort of German?)

Comment: @TimLymington Uh what? First, where did I call him a Sachsenhauser, and what does his father have to do with this anyway?

Comment: '*Æ*lfred' is Saxon, and no doubt used by historians. "Alfred the Great" or "King Alfred" has entirely different connotations.

Comment: @TimLymington The OED’s citation uses "Ælfred". I didn”t think I should rewrite that.

Comment: @tchrist So interesting to see how language diversifies and then re-merges.

Comment: @TimLymington My apologies: I mis-read the citation, and have amended it to be the abbot not the king.

Comment: @TimLymington: I'm confused by your remark. Are you being arch? Ælfred was most certainly Saxon, as was his father, King Æthelwulf, who bested the Mercians, another Saxon kingdom, to allow West Seaxe to rise to prominence.

Comment: @tchrist Thank you for this thorough and very enlightening explanation. I don't claim to fully understand all of its historic implications, but I'm happy just knowing that they are indeed related.

Comment: @Robusto: the linguistic point is that "Ælfred of West Seaxe" is very definitely not interchangeable with "King Alfred the Great" even though they refer to the same person. There are nationalistuic subtleties beyond that, but this is probably not the place.

Answer (score 4):

Typically a handyman performs **odd jobs** upon request:

> odd job
>   /ad dʒab/   (noun)
>
> A casual or isolated piece of work, especially one of a routine
>   domestic or manual nature.
>
> ‘he takes odd jobs, but nothing that would lead to a career’

Source: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/odd_job